# Is there any difference between structure and union if we have only one member?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, struct, unions

I would like to know the difference between structure and union for one member data type if there is any.

Comment: you can read about that yourself by a simple search on Google.

Comment: @Begueradj: Maybe, but the point is somewhat subtle, and I might not be inclined to trust the first thing Google throws at me.

Comment: Concerning POD and aggregates with additional discussion of changes for C++11 see [What are aggregates and PODs and how are they special](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)

Comment: Instead of closing, maybe move to Programmers?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In C: None. The famous "space-saving joke" `#define struct union` is almost not a joke.

In C++98: Unions can only have [POD members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/146454/1221252), non-union classes can have arbitrary members.

In C++11: Unions can have arbitrary data members of object type (but not of reference type), but their use is more restricted that that of non-union classes. (Namely: a union cannot have virtual member functions, cannot be a base class and cannot have base classes.) Also, you have to write more code to make a one-member union work as opposed to a one-member non-union class, since you have to write constructors and the destructor yourself.

Comment: Isn't an implementation allowed to have padding in a structure, but not in a union?

Comment: @mafso: I don't think so. The only constraint I see is this: "The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its non-static data members."

Comment: No padding allowed *before* the first member of a struct and there may be padding at the end for both union and structure. So no difference as far as single member union vs struct is concerned.

Comment: Maybe worth a quick one-line shout-out to readability and maintainability (i.e. doesn't break when you add member #2).